# Converting .php link with variable to .html

Tags: php, html, seo

I I am trying to convert php links with variables to html link (like on SMF) so increase seo of my site,

My links are like:

> > http://site.com/pages/page1.php?v1=var1&v2=var2&v3=var3&v4=var4

or:

> > http://site.com/pages/?v1=var1&v2=var2&v3=var3&v4=var4

I need it to look like this:

> > http://site.com/pages/page1.var1.var2.var3.var4.html

or

> > http://site.com/pages/var1.var2.var3.var4.html

or

> > http://site.com/page.php/var1,var2.var3.var4.html

linke in SMF forums:

> > http://forum.com/index.php/topic,9197.0.html

How to do that and alos be able to GET those variable values?

Comment: .htaccess with mod_rewrite is the answer. It's quite a complex subject, so you'll need to read a few tutorials, but those keywords should give you enough to start googling.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to learn how to implement URL rewriting.  I know PHP runs on Windows in IIS, but I'm going to go ahead and assume you are probably running Apache.  Just read up on redirecting with [.htaccess](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Htaccess) files and mod_rewrite.  There's also something similar (that, alas, you have to pay for) called ISAPI Rewrite for windows servers which I've used plenty of times.  And if you don't want to use a third party plugin and you have server 2008, the wizards for IIS do a pretty decent job and they just modify your web.config file directly to do the redirects.

Comment: Actually I use Apache and linux hosting ! , I don't want to redirect .php links to .html, I edited the question if that would help!

Comment: Of course. You rewrite the .html links to go to your your php pages.  You'd grab parts of your urls, and they become different parts of your rewritten urls.  URL rewriting allows you to keep a totally different URL structure available to the web that what you have on the file system.

Comment: Just to clarify what JayC said, you want to do rewriting and not redirecting. A rewrite lets you do stuff behind the scenes. e.g. have a page called /pages/var1/var2 get it's content from a page called /page.php?v1=var1&v2=var2 without the viewer ever knowing.

Answer (score 0):

you might want to try to research about URL encoding that's what i know if you like to change how your links display the url... hope my answer is enough :)

http://www.jaywebtechnologies.co.cc

Answer (score 0):

I see that your issue is already solved (for Linux).
If anyone has the same problem with a Windows Server, you can use Ionics ISAPI Rewrite Filter

http://iirf.codeplex.com/

I've been using it for years now, and it works perfectly. Just wanted to post it here in case anybody needs it.